# How to implement webpack's hashed css files into my index.php?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, hash, minify

I set up a webpack configuration, that uses the **MiniCssExtractPlugin** to compile my css into a single file into my public folder.

```
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css'
    }),
```

The final file looks like this:

> styles.f14f755f197392ce2228.css

I also use an index.php file, which just get's copied into the public folder.

My question now is:
**How do I include my hashed CSS file inside my index.php file without altering the name on each build manually?**
Is there some kind of helper function that gives me the name of the css file?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a function in wordpress that reads hashed css/js.
You just have to adapt it;)

```
function kodywig_matchFile($partOfName, $folder) {
  $handler = get_template_directory().'/assets/'.$folder;
  $openHandler = opendir($handler);
  while ($file = readdir($openHandler)) {
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
      if (preg_match("/^".$partOfName."\w+.(".$folder.")/i", $file, $name)) {
        return $name[0];
      }
    }
  }
  closedir($openHandler);
}
```

how to use it

```
echo '<link href="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/' . kodywig_matchFile('styles-', 'css') . '" rel="stylesheet">';
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response, do you import the file in wordpress as shown or do you enqueue it?

Comment: Can you maybe give an example on how your stylesheet is named and placed in the folder?

Comment: Here you have the whole example [docker-wordpress-xdebug](https://github.com/tomik23/docker-wordpress-xdebug/blob/master/wp-content/themes/newTemplate/inc/themename_styles.scripts.php). It's just a template, but it works;)

Comment: Okay, I tried it but it didn't work, my folder public has the subfolder assets/css like in your example, do I need to trigger functions php manually or is this done by wordpress?

Comment: Refreshing the site should download css/js, but if you have plugins, e.g. for file caching, you must disable them.
In my example, everything works automatically, changes in php, css and js generate css/js and save automatically to the wordpress template and reload it and refresh the page preview.
Well, unfortunately I can't help, there can be many reasons why it doesn't work for you. Without your code, I can only predict it;)

Comment: Okay, thank you :) What code would be useful fpr you? I just want to create a theme from scratch and I want to enqueue the correct files. I now used your code in my functions.php and inside the index.php I execute wp_head().

Comment: I hope it works already. As for the code, put the code here, for example on github. So that you can see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the awesome help from `@Grzegorz T`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868906/2813238), I've done this function which currently using on my php app (not Wordpress):

```php
  function get_asset($filename)
  {

    $dirName = dirname($filename); // if we have a file name like dir1/dir2/style.css
    $fileBaseName = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // Just the file name
    $fileExt = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // Just the file extension
    // $assetType handles the asset folder inside the dist folder
    switch ($fileExt) {
      case 'js':
        $assetType = 'scripts'; // dir/scripts
        break;
      case 'png':
      case 'jpg':
      case 'gif':
      case 'ico':
        $assetType = 'images'; // dir/images
        break;
      default:
        $assetType = 'styles'; // dir/styles
    }

    // if the file is inside another folder inside "dist" folder
    if ($dirName != '.') {
      $handler = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dist/$assetType/$dirName/";
      $externalHandler = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/dist/$assetType/$dirName/"; // for viewing it. e.g: http://example.com/dist/styles/style1/main.css
    } else {
      $handler = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dist/$assetType/";
      $externalHandler = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/dist/$assetType/"; // for viewing it. e.g: http://example.com/dist/styles/main.css
    }

    $openHandler = opendir($handler);
    while ($file = readdir($openHandler)) {
      if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
        if (preg_match("/^" . $fileBaseName . "(.\w+)?." . $fileExt . "/i", $file, $name)) {
          return $externalHandler . $name[0];
        }
      }
    }
    closedir($openHandler);
  }
```

The benefits of this function:

- You can use it to get `css`, `js`, or `images`, having a hash in the name or not.
- You can use it even if the file inside nested folders of the `dist` folder...which `webpack` will build and bundle all your styles and scripts inside.

### How to use

**File structure example:**

```
|-- dist
|    |--  images
|    |    |-- admin
|    |        |-- test
|    |            |-- no-user2.png
|    |--  styles
|    |    |--  style-en.210b2f23cdb14668c0f1.css
|    |--  scripts
```

**Example 1: Hashed style**

`echo (get_asset('style-en.css'));`

This gets:

`website.local/dist/styles/style-en.210b2f23cdb14668c0f1.css`

**Example 2: Nested image**

`echo (get_asset('admin/test/no-user2.png'));`

This gets:

`example.local/dist/images/admin/test/no-user2.png`

---

### Updated Way 2:

I've just found another awesome way with Webpack, by using [Webpack Assets Manifest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sharkcore/webpack-assets-manifest) plugin. This generates a `JSON` file that matches the original filename with the hashed version.

After generating the final `JSON` file, you can read the json file using PHP and call the needed files.